# Tau weapon. Can't get a proper circle on the weapon

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image]
[image]

I'm trying to obtain a perfect circular shape. On the right I'm just adding 2 edges around the middle, but it gives me an imperfectly circular shape, where I am trying to obtain a result equal to the one on the left. It is perfectly rounded but that will change when I do the same thing, as I did on the right.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to the number of edges you have.

In a normal circle with 8 vertices,if you applied a subsurface modifier it will look like a perfect circle,While if you had the same amount of vertices bu one of them is not connected to the other you won't get a decent result because subsurface will be applied to each independently so they won't smooth as a whole.

[image: Example]

As you can see here,although they have the same number of vertices and the same position of each,hey aren't similar because subsurface need them to be joined to be able to smooth them.

**The only solution is to increase the number of vertices:**

**This is 16 vertices instead of 8:**

[image: Example 2]

**And his is 32 instead of 16:**

[image: Example 23]

Comment: Tried adding more vertices, gave me a much better result!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Two methods. Method 1 is to make the two elements comprising the weapon as separate meshes neither of which affects the other.  Method 2 is to create Tse circular mesh, and choose two points on the circumference from which to extrude the horizontal element.

Answer (score 0):

Mean creases try to retain mesh shape before subdivision, useful for hard surface modelling. 
Simple to use, select edge / loop and slide to desired segment (Shift + E shortcut)

They can be bevelled afterwards too.

There is a possibility that mesh in question does not have proper topology. Is a 'mirror' modifier out of the question?
[image]

[image]